# How to get the Windows Group name when no user login exists

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where a user can log in to a SQL Server through their Windows group. The user itself has no login nor a user in the database.

I would then like to get the name of the windows group through which the user is logged. However, `suser_sname()` returns the actual user name. `suser_sid()` does not help me either.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If a Windows user is a member of two different Windows groups, which one do you expect SQL Server to pick?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I should have been clear about this. I'm not expecting SQL Server to pick one - if there is more than one group, I would like to get all of them.
To make a long story short... if a user is logged in through a Windows Group and not a user, I'd like to know which one(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @user SYSNAME;
SET @user = SUSER_SNAME();
EXEC xp_logininfo @user, 'all';
```

This will return rows for any group the user is in (the rows will have non-null values in the `permission path` column). But it will also return a row for their own username (in my case `permission path` was null for that row).

You can also see all the *possible* groups you might expect to see with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.server_principals
  WHERE type = 'G'; -- type_desc = 'WINDOWS_GROUP'
```

The user may also be a member of other AD groups that haven't been registered with SQL Server. You'll need to go out to AD for that.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - just what I was looking for.